# Do not accept inputs that are same in the array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make a program that will not accept duplicates from user input. If user inputs the same integer from the array, it errors or prints out the integers that were already inputted.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int[] arr = new int[5];
int[] dup = new int[5];
int duplicate;

for ( int i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++ ) 
{
    System.out.println ("Enter integer: ");
    arr[i] = input.nextInt();

    if((arr[i] >=10) && (arr[i] <=100))
    {
        System.out.printf("Output: %d\t",arr[i]);

        for(int j = 0 ; j < arr[i] ; j++)
        {
            if(dup[j] == arr[i])
            {
                dup[j] = arr[i];
                duplicate = dup[j];
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println ("enter number between 10-100");
    }

}
```

I expect to get

Enter integer: 10
Output: 10

Enter integer: 20
Output: 10 20

Enter integer: 10

No duplication
Output: 10 20

Comment: can someone help me finish this code. My brain is already drain.

Comment: What's the `dup` array meant to do?  Why not just look through `arr` to see if the user's input is already in there?

Comment: your approach isn't correct. Why do you need two arrays to check for duplicates and why are you printing the value just after validating it. You can do this in just one loop, why two loops ?

Comment: Do you really need to use an array? You can use `HashSet` (`Set` interface). A `Set` is a `Collection` that cannot contain duplicate elements.

Comment: @LalitMehra the nested for loop is to check for duplicates. Because i expect to have an output like what i stated above.

Comment: @jpllosa i dont have any idea about HashSet, i only knew basic java syntax.

Comment: please user arrays please

Comment: @newbiesj you are running a loop from 0 to the value in arr[i], it should be i. Plus your logic isn't correct.

Comment: @LalitMehra i want to use array to store into it. Yes because my brain cells are now all weak hehe

Comment: @lalitMehra help me make this possible with arrays please

Answer (score 0):

You can use set to remove duplicate values and print only originals.

```
 int Numbers[] = new int[10];
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    Scanner Number = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0; i < Numbers.length; i++){
     System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
    Numbers[i]= Number.nextInt();
    set.add(new Integer(Numbers[i]));

    if(i == Numbers.length) {
        break;
    }

}
System.out.println("Distinct Values  " + Arrays.toString(set.toArray()));
```

I/P == 10,10,10,10,20,20,50,30,30,30
O/P == 10,20,50,30

Comment: Thank you. I somehow understand your algorithm but I don't know how HashSet works and I expected to use basic java syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HashSet` collection to store unique elements

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
HashSet<Integer> nums = new HashSet<Integer>();
int n = 5; //number of iterations

for ( int i = 0 ; i < n; i++ ) 
{
    System.out.println ("Enter integer: ");
    int num = input.nextInt();

    if((num >=10) && (num <=100))
    {
        boolean isUnique = nums.add(num); //if number is unique returns true

        if (isUnique)
            System.out.printf("Output: %d\n", num);
        else {
            System.out.print("No duplication Output:");
            for (int item: nums)
                System.out.printf(" %d", item);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println ("enter number between 10-100");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you but can you do it without using HashSet because i no have any idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arr = new int[5];
    int duplicate;
    boolean isDuplicate = true;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++ ) {

        isDuplicate = true;
        System.out.println ("Enter integer: ");
        duplicate = input.nextInt();
        if((duplicate >=10) && (duplicate <=100)) {

            for(int j = 0 ; j < i ; j++) {
                if(arr[j] == duplicate) {
                    isDuplicate = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(isDuplicate) {
                arr[i] = duplicate;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println ("enter number between 10-100");
            i--;
        }
    }
```

you can print array using "System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr))"

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your approach a bit to make you understand

```
package so.questions.array;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayDuplicates {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] arr = new int[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            boolean flag = false;
            System.out.println("Enter integer: ");
            int val = scanner.nextInt();

            if (val >= 10 && val <= 100) {
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    if (val == arr[j]) {
                        flag = true;
                        i--;
                        break;
                    } 
                }
                if(!flag) {
                    arr[i] = val;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("enter number between 10-100");
            }

            System.out.print("Output:");
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.printf(" %d\t", arr[j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arr = new int[5];
    int index  = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        System.out.println ("Enter integer: ");
        int input = sc.nextInt();
        if(input >= 10 && input<=100) {
        if(index == 0) {
            arr[index] = input;
            index++;
        }
        else {
            int k=index;
            boolean dupExist = false;
            while(k>=0) {
                if(arr[k]==input) {
                    dupExist = true;
                    break;
                }
                k--;
            }
            if(!dupExist) {
                arr[index] = input;
                index++;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Output:");
        for(int k=0;k<index;k++) {
            System.out.print(arr[k]+"  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println ("enter number between 10-100");
            i--;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `HashSet`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] arr = new int[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter integer: ");
        int temp = input.nextInt();

        if (isFound(temp, arr)) { // if temp is found in arr
            System.out.println("No duplication");
        } else {
            if ((temp >= 10) && (temp <= 100)) {
                arr[i] = temp;
                System.out.print("Output: ");

                for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(" " + arr[j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                System.out.println("enter number between 10-100");
            }
        }
    }

    input.close();

  }

  private static boolean isFound(int temp, int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == temp) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```